# What is the difference between vm_insert_page() and remap_pfn_range()?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, posix, linux-device-driver, mmap

I want to map device  memory (NIC) to the kernel space memory region by using `ioremap_wc()`. And then I want to remap memory region from kernel space to user space, and I can use 2 functions for this: `vm_insert_page()` and `remap_pfn_range()`

POSIX `mmap(3)` usually use the second: `remap_pfn_range()`

What is the difference between `vm_insert_page()` and `remap_pfn_range()`, and when do I need to use `vm_insert_page()` instead of `remap_pfn_range()`?

Answer (score 4):

As their name suggest `vm_insert_page()` map a **single page**, while `remap_pfn_range()` maps a consecutive block of **kernel memory**. Check the prototypes and comments [vm_insert_page](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L1540), [remap_pfn_range](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L1731)

For example, you can use `vm_insert_page` to map `vmalloc` aree

```
do {
    page = vmalloc_to_page(vaddr);
    vm_insert_page(vma, uaddr, page);
    vaddr += PAGE_SIZE;
} while(/* there is something to map */);
```

it is not possible using `remap_pfn_range` because it maps only a consecutive block of kernel memory.

Another difference is that with `remap_pfn_range` you can map not only RAM buffers, but other ranges. With `vm_inser_page` you can map only RAM buffers

An [explanation](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/3/16/170) from Linus

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean, that I can't use `vm_inser_page` to remap device memory (NIC) region from kernel space to user space, because *"With vm_inser_page you can map only RAM buffers"*?

Comment: exactly, you can map only `page` with `vm_insert_page`

Comment: I'm trying to remap memory allocated using kzalloc_node() using remap_pfn_range() in driver's mmap() function and free the memory using kfree() in close function in vm_operations_struct. However, my system crashes after some time, with crash trace pointing to kmem_cache_alloc. I'm wondering what might be going wrong and how can I debug this further. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

`vm_insert_page()` allows drivers to insert individual pages they've allocated into a user vma. The page has to be allocate within the kernel independently. It requires the page be an order-zero allocation obtained for this purpose. It does not put out warnings, and does not require that PG_reserved be set.

Traditionally, this was done with `remap_pfn_range()` which took an arbitrary page protection parameter. `vm_insert_page()` doesn't allow that. Your vma protection will have to be set up correctly, which means that if you want a shared writeable mapping, you'd better ask for a shared writeable mapping!

`remap_pfn_range()` is used for mapping or remapping a group of pages into the memory.

[Refer](http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/)

Comment: Thanks! I.e. *"which means that if you want a shared writeable mapping, you'd better ask for a shared writeable mapping!"* - Does it mean that I must to use `remap_pfn_range()` in my case, to remap device memory (NIC) region from kernel space to user space?

Answer (score 2):

In summary:

Use `remap_pfn_range` when you don't need `struct page` for the physical page frames. It will also build page table if given memory is reserved memory.
Use `vm_insert_page` for memory that requires `struct page` for the physical page frame.
(Note that there's also `vm_insert_pages`, which can insert multiple pages into a VMA.)

For direct I/O from this region, use `vm_insert_page/vm_insert_pages` as they support `get_user_page` to obtain `struct page`, which is necessary for subsequent `ext4/scatterlist` code.